# Аквариум чарт есть ли аналог на Jquery

Tags: jquery, диаграммы

Скажите пожалуйста, есть-ли аналог чарта на jquery этому https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNGI5YzcxNTUtMWZjZi00NGRmLWI4ZGEtMGJiYjgzMjIzZThmIiwidCI6IjYwZmE5ZThlLWIyZGYtNGQyNy04NDFkLWMwZDBjYmE0ZDgzMCIsImMiOjl9&pageName=ReportSection09265ffec9004b5a8645

Или можно ли самому это реализовать?

Comment: Можно самому. Это же совсем просто)

Comment: Я бы так не сказал. :-D
За деньги можете сделать?